# Touchpad cursor is jerky

Tags: 18.04, mouse, mouse-pointer

All is in the title, this on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS freshly installed. When I connect my regular mouse it works just fine but the touchpad is still jerky.

Please help me.  I've looked in a lot of places on line.

I have a ASUS laptop:

```
$ xinput list
elan1200;00 04F3:303E Touchpad
```

Comment: Please add more details about your touchpad (vendor, version, etc.). Also information from your desktop touchpad configuration would help.

Comment: @SimonSudler I have an asus laptop, when i type "xinput list" in terminal i get : elan1200;00 04F3:303E Touchpad

Answer (score 2):

In the settings for your TouchPad, disable "Tap to Click". This worked for me.

Comment: First result on duckduckgo. This correctly identifies the problem for me, good stuff!